# How to copy ActiveStorage Images used in HTML-Editors to other instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

We are using ActiveStorage for uploading images in our Rails 7 project. The URLs generated by ActiveStorage (rails_blob_path) contain a signed_id which is different on each environment because of different secret_key_base.
We are also using a HTML-Editor where you can insert images by URL.
For test purposes we are then copying the production instance to staging instance so we have the same database and image files.
The problem is that the URLs of the HTML-Editor are not available in the staging instance because it needs a different signed_id.
How can I handle this problem?

Example File in Production: /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBXUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3eea78389a718f87d2e4511b8d8d41ba75d7f184/test.jpg

Example File in Staging:
/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBXUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--7f95258e467b91aa3e79b000cc2f6cd9b93bb709/test.jpg

The difference is the signed_in, the value after "--".

If I use the same secret_key_base, the URLs are the same. But I don't want to use the same secret key on every instance.

I can handle this problem by building a custom upload for the HTML-Editor with a custom controller which handles the redirects to the ActiveStorage files. This is working but the user can not use the option to add a image by URL if it is an ActiveStorage image.